# Unable to connect to TLS enabled Informix DB from JMeter due to Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory error

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, informix

I am trying to connect to the Informix Database (only supports TLS enabled connections) using JMeter 5.4.1.

I am getting the error as:
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Socket connection to server (DB_NAME@HOST:PORT) failed. Check your server is reachable from this client on the host:port specified.)

Able to connect to the same DB using Server Studio. The issue comes only when I connect from Jmeter.

Did below so far -

1. Downloaded JDBC drivers and placed under %JMETER_HOME%/lib folder
2. Defined JDBC Connection Configuration as below -
   jdbc:informix-sqli://DB_HOST_IP:PORT/DB_NAME:INFORMIXSERVER=DB_SERVER_NAME;sslConnection=true
3. Updated SSL Configuration properties in system.properties file to enable SSL

Just to confirm I am able to connect to another Informix DB from Jmeter which accepts non-TLS connections. However, JMeter is unable to connect TLS based Informix DB.

Please help if you have come across a similar issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case the `SSLCONNECTION` parameter is case sensitive, as per [Connecting JDBC applications with SSL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc.doc/ids_jdbc_490.htm) article it should be something like:

```
jdbc:informix-sqli:localhost:9089/mydatabase:SSLCONNECTION=true
```

You can also specify truststore location and password in the URL:

```
jdbc:informix-sqli:localhost:9089/mydatabase:SSLCONNECTION=true;SSL_TRUSTSTORE=/opt/ids/.keystore;SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=password
```

If the above steps won't work you should still be able to establish the connection using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Example code:

```
System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.trustStore', '/opt/ids/.keystore')
System.setProperty('javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword', 'password')
def cds = new com.informix.jdbcx.IfxConnectionPoolDataSource()
cds.setIfxIFXHOST('localhost',)
cds.setServerName('informix_server')
cds.setPortNumber(9089)
cds.setIfxSSLCONNECTION('true')
cds.setUser('informix')
cds.setPassword('password')
cds.setDatabaseName('stores_demo')
    
conn = cds.getPooledConnection().getConnection()
```